# Capturing game controller (not keyboard) input in Unity when the application is in the background?

Tags: unity-game-engine, focus, background-process

In a nutshell, my goal is to create my own program for visually looking at game controller input.

However, it appears that once the unity application is in the background, ergo, once I switch to a different window to play a game, the controller input for my unity program is no longer read.

I've seen that the user Elringus had a project called UnityRawInput to help with this, but it only works for keyboard input. I've seen a lot of different responses related to this question that mention using native libraries to "hook" to get background input, but it apparently only works for keyboards.

What information is out there such that I can hook to game controllers themselves? I cannot seem to easily search for information pertaining to game controllers (and their various axis) themselves and not keyboards.

Why not a keyboard? Because I am very interested in a game controller's triggers in the way where, when pressed slightly, it can preform "weaker" actions rather than being pressed all the way, which a keyboard *cannot* discern as far as I can tell.

Though, wherever the solution might be, even outside of Unity, I'd like to know. Thanks! :D

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Unity. You might be interested in [NohBoard](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/nohboard.44/) instead. Its not pretty, I'll grant that, but it functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! NohBoard seems interesting, though I'd still want to work on my own program since I want to add a stopwatch feature to buttons to track how much time passes whenever certain buttons are pressed. I'd like to focus on how exactly can I get controller input data rather than from a keyboard, since what I am interested in are a controller's triggers and how, when pressed slightly, it does a "weaker" action rather than a full on press to the trigger.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project, but again, I don't think you can do that with Unity.